# Actionscript 3: Unintended interruption on MouseOver-listener from moving sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, hover, mouseevent, sprite, mouseover

On my stage I have several DisplayObjects. To some of them I have applied a MouseOver functions.

These functions are primarily like this:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverHandler);

private function hoverHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.alpha = 2 * this.alpha;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, awayHandler);
    }

private function awayHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.alpha = this.alpha / 2;
    }
```

This works fine until some of my moving sprites suddenly also is above one of the sprites I have applied Mouseover functions to. Then my MouseOver-function can no longer detect if the mouse is on the sprite.

This is rather disturbing for the usability of my code. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can set `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` of the Sprites getting in the way to `false`:

```
aboveSprite.mouseEnabled = false;
aboveSprite.mouseChildren = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use somethng like:

```
 mc_1.hitTestObject(mc_2);
```

to determine an overlap. Then discover which MovieClip is 'above' the other with something like

```
 parent.getChildIndex(this)
```

Then use `mouseEnabled = false` to de-sensitize the MovieClip that you don't want to respond.

Your exact code may vary somewhat depending on the setup.